# Cannot update table with condition call on that table

Tags: mysql

I try to update my table by call the condition on that table, and get the error.

```
update grade G
set G.`score` = G.`score` + 5
where G.`snum` IN (select G1.`snum` from grade G1 where G1.`cname` ='Database Systems' And G1.`score` <> 'NULL' AND G1.`score` <= 95));
```

I have no idea why it give me syntax error
since this bellow line gave me 2 snum that meet the condition.

```
where G.`snum` IN (select G1.`snum` from grade G1 where G1.`cname` ='Database Systems' And G1.`score` <> 'NULL' AND G1.`score` <= 95));
```

Comment: You are closing query with two parentheses and must be one.  Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the same table you don't need a subquery for it, just add your conditions directly on the `where` clause:

```
update grade G
   set G.`score` = G.`score` + 5
 where G.`cname` ='Database Systems' 
   And G.`score` <> 'NULL'
   AND G.`score` <= 95;
```

And this `And G.score <> 'NULL'` here should be `G.score is not null` instead probably. unless you have that null as string

Answer (score 0):

At the end you have 2 closing bracket remove 1 bracket

Comment: "closing parentheses" :)

Comment: He has only 1 starting parentheses so need of 2 end parentheses

Comment: it does not work that way since I do not allow to update the table that I call in condition. I dont mean to ask about )